# Tweepy: how do I pass data from def on_data to another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I'm very new to Python and I am playing around with my Raspberry Pi and Tweepy. I have some stuff connected via GPIO, and I'd like to control a motor using the sentiment polarity value. The motor should turn on and off like a heart beat (on for 0.1 sec, off for a second, then loops). I would like to change the BPM of the motor according to the sentiment polarity value. However, if I add sleep to the code, Tweepy naturally slows down. Therefore I want to run the motor code in another thread, so that on_data can run without any sleep code, and then I can do any further processing separate from on_data.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to pass the value to that separate thread, however. What's the easiest way to do that?

```
# Twitter API imports
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from textblob import TextBlob
import json
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

# Import multithreading
from threading import Thread

# RPi Setup
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO          
from time import sleep
import time
import math

# import twitter keys and tokens (hidden for stackoverflow, of course)
consumer_key= ''
consumer_secret= ''
access_token= ''
access_token_secret= ''


# ---Motor setup---
# Initiliaze motor connections
in1 = 17
in2 = 27
en = 25
temp1=1
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Setup the motor
GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en,GPIO.OUT)

# Start the motor
GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
 
# Setup and start PWM
motorp=GPIO.PWM(en,1000)
motorp.start(0)


#  ---Arduino map function---
def _map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
    return int((x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min)
    
    
class TweetStreamListener(StreamListener):

    # on success
    def on_data(self, data):

        # decode json
        dict_data = json.loads(data)

        # pass tweet into TextBlob
        tweet = TextBlob(dict_data["text"])
        
        # output sentiment polarity
        print ("sentiment value: ", tweet.sentiment.polarity)

        # determine if sentiment is positive, negative, or neutral
        if tweet.sentiment.polarity < 0:
            sentiment = "negative"
        elif tweet.sentiment.polarity == 0:
            sentiment = "neutral"
        else:
            sentiment = "positive"

        # output sentiment
        print ("sentiment: ", sentiment)
        print("\n")

    # on failure
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
        
        
    # Motor heart beat    
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
       
    def terminate(self):  
        self._running = False

    def sentiment_thread(self):
        while self._running:
            # I need 'tweet.sentiment.polarity' here to change time.sleep value, which would change according to the polarity value.
            mapped_sentiment_value = _map(tweet.sentiment.polarity, -1, 1, 1, 3)
            
            motorp.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            motorp.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
            time.sleep(mapped_sentiment_value)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create instance of the tweepy tweet stream listener
    listener = TweetStreamListener()
    
    # start the motor heartbeat
    heartbeatthread = Thread(target=listener.sentiment_thread)
    heartbeatthread.start()
    
    # set twitter keys/tokens
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    # create instance of the tweepy stream
    stream = Stream(auth, listener)

    # search twitter for "congress" keyword
    stream.filter(track=['congress'], is_async=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `tweet` is only local to your `on_data` method.

My recommendation would be to save `tweet` as a class attribute instead.

```
def __init__(self):
    self._running = True
    self.tweet = None

def on_data(self, data):
    # decode json
    dict_data = json.loads(data)

    # pass tweet into TextBlob
    self.tweet = TextBlob(dict_data["text"])
    
    # output sentiment polarity
    print ("sentiment value: ", self.tweet.sentiment.polarity)

    # determine if sentiment is positive, negative, or neutral
    if self.tweet.sentiment.polarity < 0:
        sentiment = "negative"
    elif self.tweet.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        sentiment = "neutral"
    else:
        sentiment = "positive"

    # output sentiment
    print ("sentiment: ", sentiment)
    print("\n")


def sentiment_thread(self):
    while self._running:
        if not self.tweet:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        mapped_sentiment_value = _map(self.tweet.sentiment.polarity, -1, 1, 1, 3)
        motorp.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        motorp.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        time.sleep(mapped_sentiment_value)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work:

mapped_sentiment_value = _map(self.tweet.sentiment.polarity, -1, 1, 1, 3)
AttributeError: 'TweetStreamListener' object has no attribute 'tweet'

Not sure what's going wrong here. :/

Comment: @deadboy42 you're receiving that error because you're starting the thread before you executed `on_data`. In other words, `self.tweet` does not exist until `on_data` is run at least once.

Comment: Aha, makes sense, thank you. Moved heartbeatthread.start() to the end of main, now there's no error, however, nothing happens in that thread either, not even a simple print. I guess since stream.filter(track=['congress']) is before heartbeatthread.start() and it runs continuously, thread.start() isn't even executed? Am I correct? I tried starting the thread before executing the stream.filter line, but it gave the same 'object has no atrribute' error. What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: @deadboy42 you're welcome. I edited my original answer to handle the issue you're describing the most simple way. Please read it over and let me know if that solves it!

Comment: That did it! Thank you, great and clear explanation! Everything seems so simple now :)